# rest api get category search by name

Tags: magento-2.1

How can I get a category filter by name?

If I used

> http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories?
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=Robots&
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

Then it returned me all categories but I want only the category with name = `Robots`

Is it possible?

Thanks

---

thanks for your help

But if I send:

> http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/list?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Robots&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

Then I get:

> {
>       "message": "Invalid type for value: \"list\". Expected Type: \"int\"." }

If I send:

> http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Robots&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

I get all the categories

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having a similar problem and finding nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `/V1/categories/list` instead of `/V1/categories`. And modify your parameters from `filter_groups` to `filterGroups`, and `condition_type` to `conditionType`. So that:

> http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Robots&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogCategoryListV1/catalogCategoryListV1GetListGet